# Why i am getting previous session data for current session in codeiginitor even after destroying previous session

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session

I am facing problem in function `profile()`. In this method I am fetching data from email using session.

When I login, displaying current data. But when I click on profile it displays previous session data and after refresh it become current session data.
[image] 
last session data

after refresh display current session
[image]

my controller file is `admin.php`.

**admin.php**

```
<?php 
class Admin extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        // Load form helper library
        $this->load->helper('form');
        //Load foam valodation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // Load the model
           $this->load->model('adminmodel');
    }

    public function index(){

        // Load our view to be displayed        
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }

// Check for Admin login process    
    public function dashboard(){        

        // Validate the user can login      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)   //checking validation
          {         
            if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
            {
                $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('admin/login');
            }           
          } 

         else
         {   //validation are true                           
            if (isset($_POST['login']))
            {
                $email = $this->input->post('email');
                $password =$this->input->post('password');
                // Validate the admin can login
                $result = $this->adminmodel->validate($email,$password);
                if ($result) {//if the user credidential is validated
                    $data = array(
                            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                            'is_logged_in' => true
                    );
                    print_r($data);
                }
                // Add user data in session
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                //load dashboard and passing value
                $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$result);
            }
         }
    } //end of dashboard

    public function profile(){
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $result = $this->adminmodel->fetchdata($email);
        print_r($result);
        $this->load->view('admin/profile',$result);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failed profile";
        }

    } // end of profile 

    // Logout from admin page
    public function logout() {

        // Removing session data
        $sess_array = array(
                'email' => '',
                'is_logged_in'=>false               
                           );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($sess_array);
        $data['message_display'] = 'Successfully Logout';
        $this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

---

**model file**

adminmodel.php

```
<?php
class Adminmodel extends CI_Model{

        public function validate($email,$password)
        {   
          $query = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])
                           ->from('login')                
                           ->get();               
           $result = $query->row();
            return $result;     
         }

         public function fetchdata($email)
         {
            $query = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email])
            ->from('login')
            ->get();
            $result = $query->row();
            return $result;
         }
}
```

---

**profile.php**

```
<?php

echo " I am in Profile " . $email;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Name : <input type = "text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><p>
    <p>Mobile : <input type = "text" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>" /> </p>
    <p>Address : <input type = "text" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" /> </p>
    <p>Email : <input type = "text" value=" <?php echo $email;?>" /> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue if you manually need to refresh to see the current session data. Refresh should not change the session data, it should be there on the first load. But the question is, does this first load even happen or does the page come straight from the cache of the webserver or browser. I'd recommend including a timestamp into the page and wee if that displays the correct time with the wrong data first to make sure that the page is actually loaded on clicking on the profile.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following, after logount instead of unset data, destroy the session entirely

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```